# Run Siri commands in a shortcut on iOS

Tags: iphone, siri, shortcuts-app

I would like to make a routine shortcut. I'd like it to run commands that Siri can understand but the apps don't have Shortcuts actions for:

1. "What's the weather?"
2. "Play the news"
3. "Shuffle my Mix playlist"

Is there a way to have Siri execute text that is specified in a Shortcuts action?

Comment: Definitely possible. But I think the news won't be as elegant as I would like. Wish we could tap into Alexa's news api.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED: This new code will help you a lot, tell me if you need anything else. :)

```
Get Current Weather
At: Current Location - Custom Location

Get Playlist
Playlist: [Select Playlist]

Play Music
Shuffle: Off - (Songs)
Repeat: None - One - (All)

Show Alert
Title: Weather
Message:
- Currently -
(Weather Conditions)

Show Cancel Button: OFF

Open App
App: News
```

If you want the code to appear somewhere else and not in an alert, then please comment and tell me & I will fix it to your choosing.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: @jon Onstott, I updated my answer to fit all of your needs, but it may not be exactly as expected, but this is pretty much as close as you can get.

Comment: The idea would be to redact Siri questions and let it handle them from a shortcut.

Comment: Where would you put the code to run it in the shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

Get the weather by:

```
get details of weather conditions
get Name
```

I don't think there is a news function.

You can play but not shuffle a playlist:

```
Get playlist
Playlist
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to build a shortcut for the news.  This is built in to Siri now.
Try saying "Hey Siri, play me the news."
Or, get specific with "Hey Siri, play me the news from npr (or Washington Post, or CNN and others).
Here's an article: http://osxdaily.com/2018/01/26/siri-play-news-read-news-aloud/
You can also type to Siri with "Play me the news."
Hope this helps.
- C

Comment: Ideally I'd like to say "good morning siri" to run a shortcut that does the same thing as asking siri "what's the weather", "play the news" and then "shuffle my Mix playlist".  Instead of asking siri for each thing individually.